# Can't get :after transition to work

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions, transition

I can't seem to get the opacity transition to work on an :after pseudo-element, but the same transition on the :before element works perfectly fine. Any help is appreciated!

```
.top-nav li a:hover:after {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.top-nav li a:after {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.top-nav li a:hover:before {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-nav li a:before {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: In my tests using your CSS both :before and :after transitions work. There must be some other factor at play. One possibility is that the neighbouring button is positioned at a higher z-index, and obscures the :after content. Can you produce a reduced test case that recreates the bug? It would be helpful to see the CSS that controls the navigation layout, and your HTML markup.

Comment: Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the overlapping possibility I described in my previous comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k9euprr4/ Notice how the 3rd and 4th list items obscure their neighbours. The :after pseudo-content is still there, it is just hidden behind the neighbouring button.

Answer (score 0):

It's Working try to give width to li then It will display

```css
.top-nav li a:hover:after {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}

.top-nav li a:after {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.top-nav li a:hover:before {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-nav li a:before {
    content: "/";
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.top-nav {
  list-style: none;
}
.top-nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background:white;
  width:85px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-nav">
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```